# Ninject binding based on http method (GET or POST)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

I am using `Ninject` to bind service classes using constructor injection.

My problem is:

I have a class (controller) `User`, which takes interface `IService` in the constructor.

`IService` is implemented by `UowService` and `ReadonlyService`.

Now, I want to inject `ReadonlyService`, if the web request is a `GET`. But `UowService` for `POST`. Also, it should only configure for class `User`, meaning this binding should not affect any other class.

I know I can bind for `User` like this:

```
kernel.Bind<IService>().To<ReadonlyService>().WhenInjectedInto<User>()
```

And, following can be used to bind according to http method

```
kernel.Bind<IService>().ToMethod(ctx => 
{
    var verb = HttpContext.Current..HttpMethod;
    if (verb == "GET")
    {
        return kernel.Get<ReadonlyService>();
    }

    return kernel.Get<IService>();
});
```

But how to combine both conditions? Also, is there any better and straightforward way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can base your custom conditions on the `.When(ctx => ...` method. The following binding only applies when:

- injected into `User`
- `HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "GET"`

  ```
  kernel.Bind<IService>().To<ReadonlyService>()
    .When(r => 
         {
             // return false if not injected into User
             if (r.Target == null)
             {
                 return false;
             }
             if(!typeof(User)
                .IsAssignableFrom(r.Target.Member.ReflectedType))
             {
                 return false;
             }

             return HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "GET";
         });
  ```

Comment: If you have even more complex logic, you can also implement `Ninject.Activation.IProvider` to decide which implementation gets created.

Comment: Before posting the question, I tried with keeping HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod in .When extension. But was throwing error at runtime, saying Request is null.

Comment: @aSharma are you using async/await? Or is this outside of a request?

Comment: Not using async/await. I have parked this work for sometime.I will update as soon as I finish it.